# Fire Tablet, 7" Display, Wi-Fi Not supporting My android app

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Hi Recently I have developed one android app and uploaded to amazon app store .But the app is not compatible in **Fire Tablet, 7" Display, Wi-Fi** .Is anything I should change to make it compatible.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you write more you will get better answer!
anyway change Permissions and Feature required to false.
for example if you have camera feature but want to install you app on device without camera you should set this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

anyway send codes and manifest config.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have mentioned any mandatory feature for your application manifest file with tag `<uses-feature>`. If any feature you have listed with this tag is not available on Fire tablet, your app will become non-compatible. Check all available features list here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

E.g. Fire tablet do not have SIM Card slot and if you have mentioned this feature as mandatory for your app, you can remove this if your can work without this feature.